# consulta para verificar día de la semana

Tags: java

estoy aprendiendo sobre el uso de LocalDate, y quiero comparar el día de la semana para que cuando me devuelva SATURDAY o SUNDAY yo pueda realizar otros cálculos

estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```java
    LocalDate fechaS = LocalDate.of(dia, mes, anio);
    if(fechaS.getDayOfWeek() == SATURDAY || fechaS.getDayOfWeek() == SUNDAY){
         int diaAux = fechaS.getDayOfMonth();                
    }
```

también intente

```java
    if(fechaS.getDayOfWeek() == 6 || fechaS.getDayOfWeek() == 0){
    }
```

pero me sale "comienzo ilegal de expresion"

me pueden indicar como se puede comparar, gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El [método getDayOfWeek()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--) de la [clase LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) te devuelve un [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html). Al se un enumerable, podés utilizar el método equals ó un switch para ejecutar código basado en su valor.

**Utilizando equals**:

```
if (fechaS.getDayofWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.MONDAY) || fechaS.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY) {
  //código a ejecutar si es lunes o viernes
}
```

**Utilizando switch**:

```
switch (fechaS.getDayOfWeek()) {

  case DayOfWeek.MONDAY:
    //código a ejecutar para el lunes
  case DayOfWeek.FRIDAY:
    //código a ejecutar para el viernes
  default:
    //código a ejecutar por defecto en caso de que no se cumpla alguna de las condiciones anteriores
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero decirte que `LocalDate.of()` recibe como parámetro, primero el año, después el mes y por ultimo el día. Eso para que lo tengas en cuentas y cambies el orden de tus variables `dia`, `mes` `anio`.

```
LocalDate fechaS = LocalDate.of(2019, 04, 23); //anio,mes,dia
```

Después para comparar si el día de la semana es igual a un dia de la semana en concreto , puedes utilizar `equals()` y `SATURDAY` - `SUNDAY`  deben ir entre `""`.

Código completo:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LocalDate fechaS = LocalDate.of(2019, 04, 23);
        if(fechaS.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY)){
            // code ... 
             System.out.println(fechaS.getDayOfWeek());
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que sea de utilidad!

Comment: `fechaS.getDayOfWeek().equals("SATURDAY")` Esta parte, el `equals` espera un Object. Si introduces una cadena, no entrara en el `if`. Lo estuve probando y creo que se debe de utilizar otro método

Comment: Tienes razón, no he comprobado si entraba en el `if`.. Lo corregiré ahora

Comment: @Youshiro Gracias por el aviso, ha sido un despiste mio xD, ya lo he cambiado.

Comment: !De nada! Gajes del programador XD